# Creating a second login page that automatically logs in the user

Tags: php, jquery, authentication

I have a login page as follows:

```
<form action="?" method="post" id="frm-useracc-login" name="frm-useracc-login" >

    <div id="login-username-wrap" >

        <div class="login-input-item left">

            <div class="div-search-label left">

                <div id="div-leftheader-wrap">

                    <p class="a-topheader-infotext left"><strong>Username: </strong></p>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="login-input-content left div-subrow-style ui-corner-all">

                <input type="text" tabindex="1" name="txt-username" id="txt-username" class="input-txt-med required addr-search-input txt-username left">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="login-password-wrap" >

        <div class="login-input-item left">

            <div class="div-search-label left">

                <div id="div-leftheader-wrap">

                    <p class="a-topheader-infotext left"><strong>Password: </strong></p>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="login-input-content left div-subrow-style ui-corner-all">

                <input type="password" tabindex="1" name="txt-password" id="txt-password" class="input-txt-med required addr-search-input txt-password left">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="login-btn-bottom" class="centre-div">

        <div id="login-btn-right">

            <button name="btn-login" id="btn-login" class="btn-med ui-button ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-all btn-hover-anim btn-row-wrapper left">Login</button>
            <button name="btn-cancel" id="btn-cancel" class="btn-med ui-button ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-all btn-hover-anim btn-row-wrapper left">Cancel</button><br /><br />

        </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

And here my session.controller.php file:

[Click Here](http://www.oswestrytaxis.com/session.controller.zip)

Basically, what I want to do is create a second login page that automatically passes the value to the session controller and logs in. For example, if I go to login-guest.php, I would put the default values for username and password and then have a jquery click event that automatically logs them in using `$("#btn-login").trigger('click');`

The problem is that the session controller automatically goes back to login.php if the session has timed out and I'm not sure how I could go about achieving this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: is the problem that you don't want the user to be logged out after session timeouts?

Comment: Basically if I keep this line in the code; `header("Location: login.php");` - if I try to login through login-guest.php it redirects to login.php even though I have entered the correct username and password so I have had to comment this out which is causing problems. The other problem is that when I am logged in through login.php I would want it to redirect to login.php, if it was logged in through login-guest.php where username = `Guest` I would want it to redirect to login-guest.php. As I am commenting this line of code out, there is no re-direct what so ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned in your comment you have to know how user had logged in at the first place (login or login-guest), so you will need to have some sort of state for each user anyway.

Now if you can't increase session timeout to infinite, you probably need to store login type some where else like in cookies, or as query string in your urls.

In the case of cookie it will be something like this:

In login section of your `login-guest.php`:

```
...
$expire = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 24 + time(); // 2 years
setcookie('logintype', 'guest', $expire);
```

And this where you send user to login page:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['logintype']) && $_COOKIE['logintype']=='guest'){
    header('Location: login-guest.php');
} else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

I don't think cookies can have infinite life, so I've set expiry to two years which you can change. Obviously It won't persist if user deletes cookies or use another browser.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have just tried this but still when I go to login-guest.php, the page doesn't load and straight away it goes to login.php, any ideas?

Comment: Also, in one of the includes I have the following:-

Comment: `if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/onlinebookingv4/login.php') {
 SessionController::set_useraccount(false);
}`, would I have to add another else statement for this as well?

Comment: I assume that this problem existed before you apply the changes, and yes I looked up your php code and it seems that redirection to login page is called from `set_useraccount` function, so you will need to exclude `login-guest.php` too:

`if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/onlinebookingv4/login.php' &&
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/onlinebookingv4/login-guest.php')..`

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

You should solve your problem with an extra field on each login form with the login type (eg: registered, guest), and with this value do the desired redirect or any other logic you need?

You can also keep this login type at the session/cookie for further usage.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a simple hidden input to each form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="login_type" value="guest" />
```

You would then redirect depending upon which type of login is performed:

```
if($_POST['login_type'] == 'guest') {
    header('Location: login-guest.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

Of course there are nicer solutions, and you should always filter inputs etc, but for simplicity there you go.